# Long delay in chromedevtools timeline

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The timeline display a long delay of more than 20 min before the real recording ( just somes seconds ) . I tried to restart and clear the record and I have the same effect on next record..

[Heberger image http://img4.hostingpics.net/thumbs/mini_322349dvbug.png](http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=322349dvbug.png)

am I doing something wrong ? Someones have an idea ?

Comment: I do it again with the same version of the app and chrome but a differents OS ( Win XP vs Win 8.1). It's work perfectly with the Win 8.1 version . Maybe a Xp related issue ?